# Parameters for BJT spice-model

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, integrated-circuit, bjt, stress-testing

I need to make a spice model for BJT according to the stress test mode schedule (this is the current density and collector-base voltage). What parameters of the G-P model are responsible for these characteristics?

I tried to dig into documentation, but found no relevant information at the moment. I need to know these parameters for finishing my degree work.

Comment: The current density comes from current (a property of the whole circuit) and the geometry. The collector-base voltage is also a property of the circuit. Neither is a G-P model parameter.

Comment: Apparently a BJT is stressed in some way and apparently this causes a change in some current density and VCB. We don't know what the stress is. We don't know which current density is involved (I can think of at least four) and we don't know whether it increases or decreases. We don't know what phenomenon is causing these changes. I suppose it's possible that the Gummel-Poon parameters might model this but then again maybe not. OP has a great deal of explaining and/ or thinking to do.

Comment: I have a graph that describes 4 stress modes: JE,stress = 0.12 mA/μm^2 VCB,stress=2.5V OR VCB,stress=3.0V and two more: JE,stress = 12 mA/μm^2 VCB,stress=2.5V OR VCB,stress=3.0V. On the graph ΔIB is modeling with change 10%, 100%, 1000% when VBe=0.7V. On the axis of the abscissa is time, from 0.1 to 100000 h. Also have two graphs with ΔIB is modeling with change 1%, 10%, 100% when VBe=0.7V. And on the axis of the abscissa is VCB,stress on the first and JE,stress on the second.

Comment: @fred Also have other graphs, but my scientific supervisor highlighted these 3 as main ones at first sight.The question is how can I simulate these conditions, stress test conditions of BJT with current density and VCB, and what parameters in the GP model can be useful to do that.

Comment: @john-doty if it's not difficult for you, please take a look

Comment: I can't really decode what you're asking, but none of it seems to have any connection to SPICE or its models.